# How to use out-file command with some additions?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am writing a small script to backup all my sql databases, they slightly differ in names so i need this function which firstly out-files me the name.
since i already have script which runs for every sql db I simply need to change the backupfilename here in this command line:

```
USE [master]
RESTORE DATABASE [PMI_MIP_PMI] FROM  DISK = N'D:\backups\db1.bak' WITH  FILE = 1,  NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 50

GO

To go for that I thought about outfiling the special dbname from the backup :

function getbackupfile
{
    get-childitem "$backupfolder" | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "*db1*" } |  Where-Object {$_.extension -eq ".bak"} | select-object Name
     }
```

getbackupfile | out-file "c:\backups\lol.txt"

what i receive in my file is:

### Name

db1.bak

And what I need is only  'db1.bak' without anything like 'name'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Select -Expand Name`, that will give you only that property value instead of an object containing all the requested properties.

And to your other comment, use this:

```
# Stores the value of Name in variable DBName
... | Select -Expand Name -OutVariable DBName

# Same thing, indirectly
$DBVarName = "DBName"
... | Select -Expand Name -OutVariable $DBVarName
```

Comment: thanks! do you also know a good way to say this answer "db1.bak" in a variable ? I will accept answer in 5minutes when it's possible